# How to add new key in array PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, like this:

```php
$datas = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0
            [item] => Mak Painem
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 0
                            [field] => Warung
                            [record] => Pecel Mak Nem
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [field] => Harga
                            [record] => 10000
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [item] => Mak Yah
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 0
                            [field] => Warung
                            [record] => Pecel Makyah
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [field] => Harga
                            [record] => 12000
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

How do I add new keys in the array with PHP code?

So that it looks like this:

```php
    $datas = Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 0
                [jenis] => Data Warung
                [item] => Mak Painem
                [data] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 0
                                [field] => Warung
                                [tipe] => text
                                [record] => Pecel Mak Nem
                            )
    
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 1
                                [field] => Harga
                                [tipe] => uang
                                [record] => 10000
                            )
    
                    )
    
            )
    
        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [jenis] => Data Warung
                [item] => Mak Yah
                [data] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 0
                                [field] => Warung
                                [tipe] => text
                                [record] => Pecel Makyah
                            )
    
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 1
                                [field] => Harga
                                [tipe] => uang
                                [record] => 12000
                            )
    
                    )
    
            )
    
    )
```

I've tried this, but it hasn't worked:

```php
    foreach ($datas as $data){
                foreach($data as $row){
                    $data['jenis'] = 'Item';
                    foreach($data['data'] as $field){
                        //$data['tipe'] = 'angka';
                        
                        foreach($field as $anakfield){
                            $field['tipe'] = 'angka';
                        }
                        
                        //array_push($row,$field);
                        $data['data'] = $field;
                    }
                    //$data['data'] = $row;
                    //array_push($data['data'],$row);
                    print_r($data['data']);
                    
                }
                
                //$datas = $data;
                //print_r($datas);
            }
```

I forgot to add a variable, how can I add a type key and a type key in the $datas array
tahanks for help, I almost gave up because this program code has not been completed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a variable by reference (`&`), so it can modify the variable. The syntax is as follows:

```
foreach ($datas as &$item) {
    foreach ($item['data'] as &$data) {
        $data['tipe'] = 'angka';
    }
}

print_r($datas)
```

Comment: its work in second array, but how to push [jenis] => Data Warung to first array??

Comment: Do yourself a favour and NEVER update by reference. If you have to update a value (and your question mentions creating a NEW entry in the array, not updating) at least just use the key in the forEach: foreach( $datas as $key => $item ) and then update using $datas[$key]['tipe'] = 'angka';

Answer (score 0):

its work on this code, tengkyu Wahyu Kristianto, saya percaya anda orang indonesia

```
foreach ($datas as &$item) {
  $item['jenis'] = 'Data Warung';
  foreach ($item['data'] as &$data) {
     $data['tipe'] = 'angka';
  }
}
print_r($datas);
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to add new key value pairs to an array in php
Assuming a basic array:

```
   $array = array(
    "foo" => true,
    "bar" => "Some value"
    );
```

You can append a new value: (same result as array_push: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

```
$array[] = "Some other value";
```

Or to a specific key:

```
$array['specific_key'] = "Specific value";
```

Or you can use array_unshift to add a value to the start of an array: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php

```
array_unshift(&$array, "Value at start of array");
```

result:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(23) "Value at start of array"
  ["foo"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["bar"]=>
  string(10) "Some value"
  [1]=>
  string(16) "Some other value"
  ["specific_key"]=>
  string(14) "Specific value"
}
```